# Chosing DATABASE Table/View for my DIY project

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship

I’m trying to develop a side project for learning purposes.

I'd love to have a table/view in my MySQL database which will show quantity of item (with a brief description) and the quantity from many other shops.

I want 5 tables for the quantity, let’s call them `qty01`, `qty02` etc.
with this content:

```
Code, Description, Quantity
```

Problems:

- I don't have a table with all the possible item, is there a way I can have a table/view with all the **distinct** article/description taken from all the `qty` table ?
- Not every shop shares the same item - I need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but how do I get the code/description?
- Should I change the ER diagram?

I'd like to have the **final result more or less like this**:

```
article, descr,  qty01, qty02, qty03, qty04, qty05
```

Comment: Why do you need 5 tables? What's the difference between the tables?

Comment: There is no difference.
but i want to keep them separated as security measure,
to keep the diffent "shop" responsible for their own table.

thanks for reply @Barmar

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL` to combine all the `qtyXX` tables.